# Change the innermost element type of a jagged array — any .NET language: C#, F#, VB.NET, MSIL, C++/CLI, etc

Tags: code-golf, array

Write a class containing a method with the signature

```
System.Array ChangeElementType(System.Array jaggedArray)
```

(you may rename identifiers `ChangeElementType`, `jaggedArray` and shorten the type `System.Array` with `using` directives). The class may contain any additional members if needed.

You may assume the following preconditions (and do not need to validate them):

- The argument `jaggedArray` is not `null`.
- The argument `jaggedArray` is an array instance whose type can be represented in C# notation as `int[...]...`, i.e. the type `int` followed by 1 or more rank specifiers `[...]` where each rank specifier is a pair or square brackets with 0 or more commas between them. For example, it could be an array of type `int[]`, `int[,][][,,,]`, etc.
- No element at any level of the `jaggedArray` is `null`.
- All elements at any level of the `jaggedArray` are distinct w.r.t. reference equality (i.e. the same array instance does not appear at several different positions).
- The [lower bound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlowerbound.aspx) of any array dimension is 0.
- The length of any dimension and the total number of elements of any array fits into the type `int`.

The method must create and return an array of type `long[...]...` which is obtained from the type of `jaggedArray` by replacing `int` with `long` and keeping all rank specifiers the same. The result must have the same shape as `jaggedArray`, i.e. all array dimensions at any level must be the same. All elements at the innermost level must have the same numeric values (cast from `int` to `long`). The method must not mutate the argument `jaggedArray` or any its elements at any level.

The solution may be implemented in any language for the .NET platform: C#, F#, VB.NET, MSIL, C++/CLI, etc. All necessary `using`, `open` or `imports` directives or fully qualified names must be explicitly specified (do not rely on IDE defaults). The only referenced assembly must be `mscorlib`, no P/Invoke or COM Interop allowed. The solution cannot access any Internet services to get the result, intermediate data or to download parts of an algorithm.

It is a golf — try to minimize the number of bytes in the source.

Comment: can you clarify what `The lower bound of any array dimension is 0.` means? does this just mean to use 0-based array indexing, or maybe some notion of 0-length arrays? in general, i'm having trouble understanding the objective here

Comment: Does is have to accept both value types and reference types? I can create a version for each but I'm struggling to make one that does both.

Comment: @Pharap The innermost element type of the input array is guaranteed to be `int` and it should be converted to `long`. You do not need to handle arrays whose innermost element type is not `int` (e.g. any reference type).

Comment: @ardnew See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlowerbound

Answer (score 2):

## C# - 396 <s>440</s> <s>595</s>

I'm not entirely sure why I did this, and I can't help but feel I'm missing something. Rewrote the old `c` (for copy) method as a for-loop in the ChangeElementType method (`f`). Unless I find something substantial, I think I'll not be making this any shorter.

Golfed code:

```
using A=System.Array;using T=System.Type;class P{T g(T o){return o.IsArray?g(o.GetElementType()).MakeArrayType(o.GetArrayRank()):typeof(long);}A f(A a){var R=a;int i,r;for(var x=new int[i=r=a.Rank];;){if(i<1){if(a!=R)return R;R=A.CreateInstance(g(a.GetType().GetElementType()),x);i=1;}if(--i<r)if(x[i]-->0)i+=2;else x[i]=a.GetLength(i);else{var o=a.GetValue(x);R.SetValue(o is A?f((A)o):o,x);}}}}
```

Readable code with an excuse for a test:

```
using A=System.Array;
using T=System.Type;

class P
{
    // turns a type like "int[,][]" into "long[,][]"
    T g(T o)
    {
        return o.IsArray?g(o.GetElementType()).MakeArrayType(o.GetArrayRank()):typeof(long);
    }

    // ChangeElementType
    A f(A a)
    {
        var R=a; // R is the result, a gives us the type and a nice default value
        int i,r; // i is a counter, r is the rank

        // this loop first counts backwards filling the x array with the dimension lengths
        // then it does a tree traversal and copies things about
        for(var x=new int[i=r=a.Rank];;) // create the x array, and sets i and r
        {
            if(i<1)
            { // gone off start
                if(a!=R) // been here before
                    return R; // return the result
                R=A.CreateInstance(g(a.GetType().GetElementType()),x); // create the array to fill
                i=1; // move to start of x
            }

            if(--i<r) // move back
                if(x[i]-->0) // decrement index
                    i+=2; // move forward instead
                else 
                    x[i]=a.GetLength(i); // reset index
            else
            {
                var o=a.GetValue(x); // get the int/array
                R.SetValue(o is A?f((A)o):o,x); // if it's an array, Change it, if not, pass it directly (the int)
            }
        }
    }

    // test method (prints True if the code works, might print False if it doesn't)    
    static void Main()
    {
        string old = "";

        var a = new int[10][,];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            a[i] = new int[3,5];

            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
                {
                    int v = i * j * k;
                    a[i][j,k] = v;
                    old += v.ToString();
                }
            }
        }

        long[][,] l = (long[][,])(new P().f(a));

        string nwe = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
                {
                    nwe += l[i][j,k].ToString();
                }
            }
        }

        System.Console.WriteLine(old == nwe);

        System.Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```